# Can I customize Remedyforce?

Tags: managed-package, force.com

So another department recently purchased Remedyforce.  I'm fairly new to Salesforce in general and I've been asked to maybe support Remedyforce.

So my question is can Remedyforce be customized?  It's a managed package so am I correct in assuming that I cannot access any code, but I can add custom fields?  But I can only do 'Admin' stuff on the custom fields or VS pages.  And future versions of Remedyforce won't overwrite my changes?

I'm needing to understand it better.  Can someone please explain what I can do, or can't do with my company's Remedyforce org at a high level.

Thanks

Comment: It's a managed package...so whatever comes with the package, you can't delete or modify it.But you can certainly do other things over the top.

Comment: None of the manages packages will override what you do and you can create fields etc

Comment: Alright, thanks for that info.  What things can be done more specifically?  Can you elaborate a bit more or provide a link to more information?   So if I add new fields they won't be overwritten by future releases?  What about edits to page layouts, etc.?

Comment: You can do whatever u want to ( just like in Salesforce) except modifying package functionalities or its schema